# I Don't Understand This Use of Recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I was reading through the answers earning a "reversal" badge and I found a question regarding recursion where the OP didn't bother to do much of their homework assignment up front. Aside from some really funny answers, @machielo posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694998/881224) in python that I had to run on my machine to get a grip on. I'm still not understanding it.

```
def recursive(x):
    if x > 10:
        print recursive(x/10)
    return x%10

>>> recursive(2678)
2
6
7
8
```

I tried out my first guess, but I know it's wrong

```
>>> 2678/10
267
>>> 267/10
26
>>> 26/10
2
>>> 2%10
2
```

Okay...that's the two. How does this evaluate the output of the other numbers in `x`?

## EDIT

It's the `print` statement that I don't get here. I modified the code as such:

```
>>> def recursive(x):
if x > 10:
    print x
    print recursive(x/10)
return x%10

>>> #I will comment the interpreter session here...
>>> recursive(2345)
2345 # first feed in...print the raw number `x`
234  # 2345/10 does equal 234...the 5 is being held back somewhere...
23   # and each pass through the recursive loop removes the last digit...
2    # but where was it being stored at, so that each evaluation of
3    # x > 10 finally started returning False
4    # and returns the number, exiting the function
5    # ...
```

I'm thinking that during each run through, the call to `print recursive(x/10)` creates a new function object, each with it's own brand new base case and input...

Another hint, anyone?

## FINALLY

Thanks to everyone. I feel I understand this now...the trick wasn't so much `print` as it was `x%10`. `2345%10 == 5`...

```
>>> def recursive(x):
print "Raw `x`:", x
if x > 10:
    print "Recurse `x`:", x
    print recursive(x/10)
print "Last `x`:", x    
return x%10

>>> recursive(2345)
Raw `x`: 2345
Recurse `x`: 2345
Raw `x`: 234
Recurse `x`: 234
Raw `x`: 23
Recurse `x`: 23
Raw `x`: 2
Last `x`: 2
2
Last `x`: 23
3
Last `x`: 234
4
Last `x`: 2345
5
```

Also, credit to whoever went in and updated the initial answer that [I previously linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1694998/881224)...I'm about to upvote your comment:

```
>>> def recursive(x):
if x >= 10:
    print recursive(x/10)    
return x%10
```

Comment: I think I don't totally understand the question. What do you mean with "each number in `x`"?

Comment: I don't want to muddy my question with all my bad guesses **but**...replacing `print recursive(x/10)` with `return recursive(x/10)` will push the base case to the first pass of recursion.

Comment: your example does not produce that output for me

Comment: @joaquin `python 2.7.1`? Could you describe your output?

Comment: @joaquin: It works for me. Python2

Comment: ouput is 2, 6, 7. I need to call `print recursive(2678)` to get the output given in the post (2,6,7,8). OK I got it: you are in python console and I was in IDE

Comment: "I'm thinking that during each run through, the call to print recursive(x/10) creates a new function object, each with it's own brand new base case and input..." Yes, this is recursion in a nutshell.  Part of what makes this particular recursive function confusing is that it calls the recursive function, then does more stuff afterward (that's not an if-else!).  This means if you don't immediately see what it does you really have to pull out the pen and paper.

Comment: @ChadMiller I commented on your answer below. I really felt it helped me understand better what was going on. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that adding a few `print` statements it's really helpful:

```
def recursive(x):
  print '[start] recursive({0})'.format(x)
  if x > 10:
    print recursive(x/10)
  print '[return] recursive({0}) = {1}'.format(x, x%10)
  return x%10

print recursive(2678)
```

The output is:

```
[start] recursive(2678)
[start] recursive(267)
[start] recursive(26)
[start] recursive(2)
[return] recursive(2) = 2
2
[return] recursive(26) = 6
6
[return] recursive(267) = 7
7
[return] recursive(2678) = 8
8
```

Comment: I copied your format and tweaked it slightly so that I would force myself to build it from memory. Good example!

Comment: @Droogans Thanks. If you want to get a  much more verbose output you can also use `traceback.print_stack`. This will print the whole stack, in particular all the calls to `recursive` one on top of each other.

Answer (score 5):

Stepping through your example in pseudocode (number of dashes indicates recursion depth):

```
-call recursive(2678)
--2678 > 10, call recursive(267)
---267 > 10, call recursive(26)
----26 > 10, call recursive(2)
-----return 2%10 (which is 2)
----print 2, then return 26 % 10 (which is 6)
---print 6, then return 267 % 10 (which is 7)
--print 7, then return 2678 % 10 (which is 8)
-return 8
```

Comment: So you're saying that the `print` statement is not evaluated until much later in the recursive loop, and even then...it doesn't actually display the results? Is that what you mean by `print 2, then return 26 % 10`? You have the last line at being `return 8`, which is why I'm thinking this.

Comment: @Droogans I think it is correct. last 8 is printed by the console

Comment: It isn't that it isn't evaluated.  The print statement cannot be resolved yet because it keeps calling the method recursively.  The values cannot be resolved until it returns a value at the bottom, hence recursion can be seen as the answer bubbling up.

Comment: @Droogans: What's happening with the inner function calls is that they are being called with print recursive(x/10).  When the recursive(x/10) evaluates, it returns a value but does not print it by default...but since it was called inside a print statement, as soon as it returns the function prints the result.  If it just said recursive(x/10) without the print it would not print anything.

Answer (score 3):

This function prints out the digits of the number.

It works like this:

```
def recursive(x):
  if x > 10:
    # Divide x by 10 and round down. This chops off the last decimal place.
    # Now feed that new x without the last decimal place back into recursive()

  # return x's last digit
```

Basically, it won't `print` anything until `x` is a single digit number.

The part you're confused about is probably why it's printing out each decimal place in that order. This happens because while the function recurses, the parent function is still running.

Just try and expand the code for that single number.

---

**Edit**: I'm confusing myself as well.

Your code calls `print` *before* `return`, which means that when the *last* level of recursion finishes, the second-to-last prints out the first digit. The same goes for the next layers.

Comment: Okay @Blender, I'll write out my horrid attempt at mimicking a stack diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind the call stack when considering recursion. The recursive call is pushing all `recursive()` function calls onto the stack before anything is printed so what you end up with on the stack is

```
recursive(2) # end condition is met so returns 2%10
recursive(26)
recursive(267)
recursive(2678) # the initial call
```

once the end condition is reached 2%10 (2) is returned to the previous function's print statement and printed, then that function returns 26%10 (6), and this continues until all the recursive function calls on the stack have returned. The result is this series of print calls:

```
print 2 
print 6
print 7
8
```

8 is not actually printed; it is just returned which is fine from the interpreter. If you wanted to be sure that it printed in for example a python script you would call `print recursive(2678)`